# Calculating salary after in array and returning answer

Tags: java, arrays

The problem:

> Write a method that takes in an array of salary values and a double
>   rise rate, to calculate and return the array of salaries after they
>   are raised. If, for example, the rise rate is 1.07 and one has the
>   salary of £20000, then after raising the salary is 20000 X 1.07 =
>   21400.

Please note: it is not a home work but past exam questions from Software & Programming 1, Birkbeck, University of London.

So far I have but I don't think it's quite correct, as after compiling, I need to click on inspect.

```
public class salary
{
    public static double [] salary ()
    {
        double [] salary = {20000};
        riseRate = 1.07;
        for (int i = 0; i<salary.length; i++)
        {
            salary [i] = salary[i] * riseRate;
        }
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: This must work, but (1) you are asked to write method taking two parameters, so ``salary`` and ``riseRate`` must be its inputs, not locals, and (2) you should clarify whether you should modify given array or create a new one.

Comment: The calculation is correct as it is, but the question wants you to pass the `salary` array and the `riseRate` as parameters.  You need to click `inspect` only because you haven't displayed the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write a method that takes in an array of salary values and a double
>   rise rate

```
public static void foo(double[] salaries, double riseRate){...}
```

> return the array of salaries after they are raised

```
public static double[] foo(double[] salaries, double riseRate){...}
```

> If, for example, the rise rate is 1.07 and one has the salary of
>   £20000, then after raising the salary is 20000 X 1.07 = 21400

```
public static double[] foo(double[] salaries, double riseRate){
    for(double salary : salaries){
        salary *= riseRate;
    }  
    return salaries;
}
```

All the information you need to construct this simple method is right there.

Comment: @pureJava, Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). You really need to go back to the basics.